# Trying to get some byte array from a helper function in to an attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, rad-controls

I am trying to get some binary data in to the "DataValue" attribute as in the below control.

```
<telerik:RadBinaryImage runat="server" ID="RadBinaryImage1" AutoAdjustImageControlSize="false" 
  DataValue='<%# getBinary(); %>' />
```

the DataValue field accepts a byte[] .

my code behind looks like this

```
public byte[] getBinary()
{
    TestDBDataContext db = new TestDBDataContext();

    var r = (from a in db.ImageTables where a.Id == 22 select a).FirstOrDefault();

    byte[] bt = r.Thumbnail.ToArray();

    return bt;    
}
```

NOTE: The control is inside a repeater control

How could I get byte array in to the DataValue attribute on the above control ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message and your markup are not consistent: in your markup you use data binding syntax `<%# ... %>` (with the `#` at the beginning) but the error message reports a code block `<% ... %>`.

Using a code block inside a control attribute is not valid ASP.NET, the text is interpreted literally, and thus is not recognized as a byte array. Make sure you use data binding syntax, can you double check?

Comment: <telerik:RadBinaryImage runat="server" ID="RadBinaryImage1" AutoAdjustImageControlSize="false" DataValue='<%# getBinary(); %>' />

i changed it back to a binding code block, it is giving me an error 

Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Comment: i removed the semi colon and that fixes the problem ! but still there is something i want to ask! How do I put the control only based on a condition ?

Comment: Binding the Visible attribute is the easiest way to accomplish that: `Visible='<%# ... %>'`

Comment: so this will output something only if the eval returns a value right ?

Comment: Yes, if the call to `Eval()` returns false then no output is rendered.